# Connection error while connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here While I am trying to connect SQL server after installation I am getting the following error. 
[image: this Error]

How to rectify the error, I have tried to restart the SQL service but it is also showing logon Failure.

[image: THis error while trying to restart the service]

- Then I found out a solution for the logon failure error is that we
  need to rewrite the password again in Logon tab and save it. But my
  problem is that where can I get the password or which password I need
  to rewrite because I don't know the actual password written on that,
  So ho Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

As this is clearly a SQL Server configuration and not a database related question you should untag everything but `sql-server` ASAP. Also, you might want to ask future questions like these in the https://dba.stackexchange.com/ forum as StackOverflow is more development focused.

Having said that, to reconfigure the SQL Server service account you need to go to the SQL Server configuration manager via Start Menu or Computer Management. There you can double click the service to see its details. In this case you can (re)set the service account from the `Log On` tab (see screenshot), here you can choose between a built-in or a managed account. Important note: it is preferred to use a domain account. Managed or Local Service account with minimal privileges are second best. It is ill-advised to use Local System for security reasons.

[image]